# Simple SQL query, but out of my field, help needed

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have 2 tables, SalesOrderHeader and SalesOrderDetail, connection between them is the SalesOrderID field, as it is presented.

[image]

I need to create a query which will show quantity (OrderQty) and sales value (OrderQty * UnitPrice) for every customer (CustomerID) in the month of August, 2012 (OrderDate). Just a heads up, OrderDate is a datetime type of field (example year-month-day 2012-09-18).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  oh.CustomerID
,       sum(od.OrderQty) as TotalUnits
,       sum(od.OrderQty * od.UnitPrice) as TotalPrice
from    SalesOrderHeader oh
left join
        SalesOrderDetails od
on      oh.SalesOrderId = od.SalesOrderId
where   '2012-08-01' <= oh.OrderDate and oh.OrderDate < '2012-09-01'
group by
        oh.CustomerID
```

Not sure what the `LineTotal` column is for, but that might be a better candidate for the total price sum.

Comment: It is ok the way it is now, LineTotal is something different completely.